# how to set cron tab to run every 10 minutes starting at xx:x8

Tags: cron

currently, my script in the cron is set to run every 10 minutes as the following:

*/10 -> this runs the script in xx:00, xx:10, xx:20 and etc.

I need the script to run every xx:08, xx:18, xx:28, xx:38

can I set it as the following:

*/10-2 ?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

```
8,18,28,38,48,58 * * * *
```

This will run the job at 8, 18, 28... minutes. Not a good solution but acceptable since we only have 6 values.

**Option 2:**

> Note: This is Non standard! May not work with every cron. as described [here](https://crontab.guru/#8/10_*_*_*_*).

```
8/10 * * * *
```

Comment: 8/10 doesn't work, I changed it to specific integers